# How to disable auto height for sliders by using React Bootstrap carousel

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Can anyone tell me how i can disable the carousel auto height? I'm using the [react bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/carousel/) but i cant find any option to disable the auto height..